# "Not declared in this scope" error resolving name of function template in a publicly derived base class template

Tags: c++

Consider ([link](http://ideone.com/EIK6LZ)):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

#pragma pack (1)

template <size_t Width>
class Base
{
public:
    char mData [Width];
    template <typename Field> Field ExtractAs () const
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast <Field> (mData);
    }
};

template <typename FieldVal>
class IntegralField
:
    public Base <sizeof (FieldVal)>
{
public:
    FieldVal GetVal () const
    {
        return ExtractAs <FieldVal> ();
    }
};

int main()
{
    char raw[4] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44};
    typedef IntegralField <uint32_t> UInt32Field;
    const UInt32Field& field =
        *reinterpret_cast <const UInt32Field*> (raw);
    const uint32_t extracted = field.GetVal();
    assert (extracted == 0x44332211);
}
```

The call:

```
return ExtractAs <FieldVal> ();
```

Fails to compile under g++ 4.7.2 with:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘FieldVal IntegralField<FieldVal>::GetVal() const’:
main.cpp:25:16: error: ‘ExtractAs’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:25:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
main.cpp:25:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:32:28: error: ‘uint32_t’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:32:36: error: template argument 1 is invalid
main.cpp:32:49: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
main.cpp:35:11: error: ‘uint32_t’ does not name a type
main.cpp:36:5: error: ‘extracted’ was not declared in this scope
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I have tried a number of tricks including `using Base::ExtractAs`, `typedef`s, etc, to no avail.

Is what I'm trying to do possible in C++03?  How can I call a function template in a base class template from a derived class template member function?  Note that I cannot use C++11.

**Edit:** When I redefine `GetVal` to be more explicit about types:

```
  FieldVal GetVal () const
    {
        static const size_t fieldSize = sizeof (FieldVal);
        typedef Base <fieldSize> MyBase;
        typedef FieldVal MyField;
        return MyBase::ExtractAs <MyField> ();
    }
```

I still get:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token
```

On: `return MyBase::ExtractAs <MyField> ();`

**Edit:** Here is the final, working code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdint.h>

#pragma pack (1)

template <size_t Width>
class Base
{
public:
    char mData [Width];
    template <typename Field> Field ExtractAs () const
    {
        return *reinterpret_cast <const Field*> (mData);
    }
};

template <typename FieldVal>
class IntegralField
:
    public Base <sizeof (FieldVal)>
{
public:
    FieldVal GetVal () const
    {
        return this->template ExtractAs<FieldVal>();
    }
};

int main()
{
    char raw[4] = {0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44};
    typedef IntegralField <uint32_t> UInt32Field;
    const UInt32Field& field =
        *reinterpret_cast <const UInt32Field*> (raw);
    const uint32_t extracted = field.GetVal();
    assert (extracted == 0x44332211);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either say:

```
return this->template ExtractAs<FieldVal>();
```

Or

```
return Base<sizeof(FieldVal)>::template ExtractAs<FieldVal>();
```

Since you are in a class template and the base is a template specialization, too, the names of base members are not automatically injected into the derived template. (Consider what happens if you specialize `Base`!)

By qualifying the name or using `this->`, you make the entire name dependent, and so it doesn't cause in error in the first phase. Also, since the name `ExtractAs` is dependent (being the nested name of a template), you have to disambiguate it as `template`.

Comment: Using @AndreyT's suggestion verbatim yields: `error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ token`.  I've tried to be even more explicit, but this still yields errors.  I edited that attempt in to my original post above.

Comment: Using the `this->` variant yields the same compiler error as my previous comment.

Comment: @JohnDibling You need a `template` disambiguator in that expression -- Change that to `this->template ExtractAs<Field>();` or `typename Base<sizeof(FieldVal)>::template ExtractAs<FieldVal>();`.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Whoops, yes indeed. I almost thought I should need that. Fixed!

Comment: @0x499602D2:  That seems to be the secret incantation I was looking for.  After I fixed up a couple other small errors (not related), this is working now.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Sorry for the back-and-forth. I really should know this better. I did write this sort of stuff extensively at some point. The key is that `ExtractAs` is a dependent name, so it needs to be disambiguated among value, type and template.

Comment: @KerrekSB:  No sweat.  I should have known it too.  In 15 years of doing C++ I've needed this construct like twice.  This was the second time.

Comment: @JohnDibling: Try writing allocators or other kinds of "rebinding" logic :-)

Comment: That was the first time. :)